# approximation of sum of matrices

Tags: matrices

I've got a general question. For the sum of the matrices $\boldsymbol C = \boldsymbol A  + \boldsymbol B$, under which conditions would one say that the approxmation $\boldsymbol C \approx \boldsymbol A $ is good and valid. What are the criteria to justify this approximation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

That really depends on what you plan to do with the matrices.   Suppose we want to solve the linear systems $Ax=d$ and $Cx=d$, for $d=[4~~ 7.999]^T$.  If $$A=\left[\begin{smallmatrix} 1&2\\2&3.999\end{smallmatrix}\right], B=\left[\begin{smallmatrix} 0.001&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$$

we might think that $A,C$ are close, but the solution for $A$ is $[2~~ 1]^T$ while the solution for $C$ is $[-0.667~~ 2.334]^T$.

If this happens we call $A$ [ill-conditioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number). See [here](http://nm.mathforcollege.com/mws/gen/04sle/mws_gen_sle_spe_adequacy.pdf) for some examples and discussion of this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In fact your right and I have to solve a set of linear equations: $\boldsymbol C \boldsymbol x = \boldsymbol b$. Furthermore A is symmetric and positive semidefinite. And I want to know whether I can save computational time by the approximation above. Analytically I can compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A,B,C$, does this help to make a good statement? For the solution of the linear system the eigenvalues and -vectors of $C$ are quite important, right? Would make sense to say that if the eigenvalues of $B$ are small this approx. is valid?

Comment: Eigenvalues don't really help you; in my example $B$ has small eigenvalues, and small entries.  Further, the eigenvalues of $A,C$ are quite similar -- one is near 5, one is near 0.

Comment: In short, not only is dropping $B$ a bad idea, even rounding the entries of your matrices might lead to catastrophic failure.

Comment: Thanks again. I now understand that if $C$ will get ill-conditioned by this approx. I will get severe problems. But in my case $C$ will be a positive semidefinite matrix (since $A$ is PSD). So, $C$ may turn by this approximation from a maybe indefinite matrix to a PSD matrix. This is also a reason for using this approximation. Can I now make a valid statement when I can use this approximation?

Comment: @bonanza, please ask another question where you give all the specifics.